# Как сохранить состояние onActivityResult

Tags: android

Есть класс `Mainmenu`, там есть метод `setActivityResult` , есть второй класс `Newgame`, там есть `setResult(Request_state_1)` который равен 0 , есть кнопка в `xml` она `android:enabled="false"`, как сделать чтобы при закрытии приложения значение `true` сохранилось, после выполнения метода `setActivityResult`. Пробую сохранить через `SheredPreference`, но не получается, что я делаю не так?

Вот код:

```
public class Mainmenu extends AppCompatActivity {
...
public static final String SaveResult = "saveresult";
public static final String SaveResultKey = "saveresultkey";
static final int Request = 1;
int Request_state_1 = 1;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bcontinue);
    ...
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SaveResult, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Request_state_1 = settings.getInt(SaveResultKey, Request_state_1);

    if (Request_state_1==0){
        btn.setEnabled(true);
        btn.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SaveResult, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt(SaveResultKey, Request_state_1);
    editor.apply();
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultCode, intent);

    if (requestcode == Request){
        if (Request_state_1==0) {
            btn.setEnabled(true);
            btn.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение. Заменил `Request_state_1` на `RESULT_OK`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultCode, intent);

if (requestcode == Request){
    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        btn.setEnabled(true);
        btn.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SaveResult, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Request_state_1 = settings.getInt(SaveResultKey, RESULT_OK);

    if (Request_state_1==RESULT_OK){
        btn.setEnabled(true);
        btn.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

При дестрое вы же сохраняете единицу, потом в `onCreate` почему-то проверяете на ноль

```
 if (Request_state_1==0){
        btn.setEnabled(true);
        btn.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
    }
```

Может быть надо `Request_state_1==1`?

Answer (score 0):

Что-то мне подсказывает что `onDestroy` не лучшее место для сохранения.
Сохраняйте сразу после того как меняете UI в `onActivityResult`.